# Problema con PHP Server, URL y cache

Tags: php, url, cache

Se supone que debería aparecerme crear, pero me lleva a admin y no puedo cambiarlo ni escribiendo en la url ni nada, lo mismo pasa con actualizar y demás me redirecciona al admin he copiado el código tal cual lo tenía en el proyecto que descargue, también en el propio que hice siguiendo el proyecto y siempre se queda en admin y no puede pasar a otra página, tampoco puedo actualizar php server cuando le doy a actualizar tengo que abrir un archivo html actualizar ese archivo y entonces php server se actualiza pero tampoco puedo moverme de admin, cambiando la url tampoco. No se a que se debe porque antes de que instalara el apache en comandos, cuando lo tenia solo en xampp funcionaba perfectamente pero después formatee el pc volví a utilizar xampp y ya no funciona bien ni php server ni actualizando en el navegador ni me lleva a la ruta que quiero, he probado de todo pero no tengo ni idea de como solucionarlo. Con otros proyectos haciéndolo de otra forma con POO también se queda en admin. He probado también inhabilitando la cache al inspeccionar pero tampoco funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola, como estas???

Comment: Hola, bien y tu? era un error de login, pero tu sabes porque no se me actualiza la  informacion del php server y del navegador cuando es codigo php? con el live server de los archivos html me funciona perfecto